# Clippath doesn't work when dynamic id's are generated

Tags: d3.js, brush

I have implemented a bar chart with brush (D3.js V3). I have applied clip-path which is working fine for a hard-coded value (`#clip`). 
But when I tried doing it with dynamic id its not working. when I click on a button which opens a model-box the height of bars is also clipped.

[Image with model popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RY1ra.png)

Thanks in advance.

```
svg.append("defs")

.append("clipPath")
//  .attr("id", container)
.attr("id", "clip")
.append("rect")
.attr("x", 0)
.attr("y", 0)
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);


 var dev = '# '+ container ;
 main.append("g")
.attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)')// this is hard coded id
//.attr('clip-path', "url("+ dev +")")// this is dynamic id
.attr("class", "bars")
```

Comment: Please use "url(dev)" instead of "url("+ dev +")". I have tried in  https://jsfiddle.net/qcmebn2x/ and its working

Comment: @dev That is wrong. In your demo you could use "url(whatsoever)" without making any difference.

Comment: Please set up a [mcve] demonstrating the issue. This will make it much easier to help you out.

Comment: @altocumulus, My bad.I thought issue is with string as url, so suggested.  With   "url("+ dev +")" also, changes are working in mentioned fiddle; I should have checked that. Thanks